# Where should I add the --rest option for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I need to use mongodb with the --rest option. But mongodb is started automatically on boot, so I guess I need to modify a file or something.

Where can I add this --rest option?

I have this file at /etc/init/mongodb.conf, not sure what to edit:

```
# Ubuntu upstart file at /etc/init/mongodb.conf

limit nofile 20000 20000

kill timeout 300 # wait 300s between SIGTERM and SIGKILL.

pre-start script
mkdir -p /var/lib/mongodb/
mkdir -p /var/log/mongodb/
end script

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

script
  ENABLE_MONGODB="yes"
  if [ -f /etc/default/mongodb ]; then . /etc/default/mongodb; fi
  if [ "x$ENABLE_MONGODB" = "xyes" ]; then exec start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --chuid mongodb --exec  /usr/bin/mongod -- --config /etc/mongodb.conf; fi
end script
```

And this file at /etc/init.d/mongodb:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
# upstart-job
#
# Symlink target for initscripts that have been converted to Upstart.

set -e

INITSCRIPT="$(basename "$0")"
JOB="${INITSCRIPT%.sh}"

if [ "$JOB" = "upstart-job" ]; then
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "Usage: upstart-job JOB COMMAND" 1>&2
    exit 1
    fi

    JOB="$1"
    INITSCRIPT="$1"
    shift
else
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 COMMAND" 1>&2
    exit 1
    fi
fi

COMMAND="$1"
shift


if [ -z "$DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE" ]; then
    ECHO=echo
else
    ECHO=:
fi

$ECHO "Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)"
$ECHO "utility, e.g. service $INITSCRIPT $COMMAND"

# Only check if jobs are disabled if the currently _running_ version of
# Upstart (which may be older than the latest _installed_ version)
# supports such a query.
#
# This check is necessary to handle the scenario when upgrading from a
# release without the 'show-config' command (introduced in
# Upstart for Ubuntu version 0.9.7) since without this check, all
# installed packages with associated Upstart jobs would be considered
# disabled.
#
# Once Upstart can maintain state on re-exec, this change can be
# dropped (since the currently running version of Upstart will always
# match the latest installed version).

UPSTART_VERSION_RUNNING=$(initctl version|awk '{print $3}'|tr -d ')')

if dpkg --compare-versions "$UPSTART_VERSION_RUNNING" ge 0.9.7
then
    initctl show-config -e "$JOB"|grep -q '^  start on' || DISABLED=1
fi

case $COMMAND in
status)
    $ECHO
    $ECHO "Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an"
    $ECHO "Upstart job, you may also use the $COMMAND(8) utility, e.g. $COMMAND $JOB"
    $COMMAND "$JOB"
    ;;
start|stop)
    $ECHO
    $ECHO "Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an"
    $ECHO "Upstart job, you may also use the $COMMAND(8) utility, e.g. $COMMAND $JOB"
    if status "$JOB" 2>/dev/null | grep -q ' start/'; then
        RUNNING=1
    fi
    if [ -z "$RUNNING" ] && [ "$COMMAND" = "stop" ]; then
        exit 0
    elif [ -n "$RUNNING" ] && [ "$COMMAND" = "start" ]; then
        exit 0
    elif [ -n "$DISABLED" ] && [ "$COMMAND" = "start" ]; then
        exit 0
    fi
    $COMMAND "$JOB"
    ;;
restart)
    $ECHO
    $ECHO "Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an"
    $ECHO "Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) and then start(8) utilities,"
    $ECHO "e.g. stop $JOB ; start $JOB. The restart(8) utility is also available."
    if status "$JOB" 2>/dev/null | grep -q ' start/'; then
        RUNNING=1
    fi
    if [ -n "$RUNNING" ] ; then
        stop "$JOB"
    fi
    # If the job is disabled and is not currently running, the job is
    # not restarted. However, if the job is disabled but has been forced into the
    # running state, we *do* stop and restart it since this is expected behaviour
    # for the admin who forced the start.
    if [ -n "$DISABLED" ] && [ -z "$RUNNING" ]; then
        exit 0
    fi
    start "$JOB"
    ;;
reload|force-reload)
    $ECHO
    $ECHO "Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an"
    $ECHO "Upstart job, you may also use the reload(8) utility, e.g. reload $JOB"
    reload "$JOB"
    ;;
*)
    $ECHO
    $ECHO "The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart" 1>&2
    $ECHO "job, but $COMMAND is not supported for Upstart jobs." 1>&2
    exit 1
esac
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's probably cleaner to enable the REST interface via `/etc/mongodb.conf` by adding a line of:

```
rest = true
```

That setting is documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/configuration-options/#rest).

Comment: FYI: For `Fedora` the files is located at `/etc/mongod.conf`. \o/

Answer (score 8):

MongoDB version 2.6 has switched to a YAML config file.  The following two entries are required to prevent the following startup warning: 
`mongodb WARNING: --rest is specified without --httpinterface`

```
net:
  http:
    enabled: true
    RESTInterfaceEnabled: true
```

Comment: Make sure that there are NO TABS in the .config file - or Mongo will fail to start.  It only allows for spaces.

Comment: also there should be space after :

Answer (score 2):

When u start the server using command `mongod` , add `--rest` option with command `mongod` like this `mongod --rest`.

refer [mongod - MongoDB Manual 2.6](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod).

After run command complete , u can use the following the simple Restful API:

```
http://127.0.0.1:28017/databaseName/collectionName/
```

[Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#simple-rest-api) is simple RestFul API Doc.

Answer (score -1):

Just start the server using `mongod --rest`

Note: By default, the rest API's are inaccessible due to security issues. The web interface is accessible at `localhost:<port>`, where the  number is `1000` more than the mongod port. For example, your mongodb server is running at `27017` (by default) then you can access mongodb at

```
http://127.0.0.1:28017/<db-name>/<collection-name>/
```