# mongodb shows an error when run on command prompt

Tags: php, mongodb, wamp

I am new to mongodb.. I am trying to integrate mongodb to wamp.. I already installed mongodb(for windows 64 bit) and its path is `C:\wamp\bin\mongodb` when run on command the following command It displays error

```
C:\Users\NITHIN>mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.3
connecting to: test
Server has startup warnings:
2014-07-04T15:00:47.944+0530 ** WARNING: --rest is specified without --httpinter
face,
2014-07-04T15:00:47.946+0530 **          enabling http interface
>
```

Anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553623/where-should-i-add-the-rest-option-for-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

The startup warning is displayed because you've enabled the simple REST API in your configuration but have not explicitly enabled the required `httpinterface` (which can be enabled independently for an http status interface without REST).

In this case the http interface is implicitly enabled .. but with a warning, in case that wasn't what you intended.

Note that the REST API is disabled by default in MongoDB 2.6+, and should only be used in development environments as it represents a security risk. For more information, see: [Security and MongoDB API Interfaces](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-interface/#rest-api).